# some defines compiled success in gcc, but g++ failed

Tags: compiler-errors, g++

I have copy some codes from project `props-3.3.9`: `readproc.c` file

then compile sucess with **gcc**, and **execute access** .

but now I want to code with c++, but g++ compile error!

the g++ report error:

```
expression of type 'void' is illegal
#define F(x) {#x, sizeof(#x)-1, (long)(&&case_##x-&&base)},
                                                    ^
readproc.c:122:9：in expansion of macro ‘F’
     F(VmHWM)
     ^
```

here are codes:

```
#define LABEL_OFFSET
typedef struct status_table_struct {
    unsigned char name[7];        // /proc/*/status field name
    unsigned char len;            // name length
#ifdef LABEL_OFFSET
    long offset;                  // jump address offset
#else
    void *addr;
#endif
} status_table_struct;


#ifdef LABEL_OFFSET
#define F(x) {#x, sizeof(#x)-1, (long)(&&case_##x-&&base)},
#else
#define F(x) {#x, sizeof(#x)-1, &&case_##x},
#endif
#define NUL  {"", 0, 0},


static const status_table_struct table[] = {
    F(VmHWM)
    NUL NUL
    F(VmLck)
    NUL
    F(VmSwap)
    F(VmRSS)
    NUL
    F(VmStk)
    NUL
    F(Tgid)
    F(State)
};
#undef F
#undef NUL


base:
case_Name:
case_ShdPnd:
case_SigBlk:
case_SigCgt:
case_SigIgn:
case_SigPnd:
case_State:
```

what's wrong with grammer?

Comment: Can you post the C code which compiles successfully, for providing context? That code on its own won't compile also with gcc

Comment: it seems that I can't post too many codes, so I can give the url at github, it is

Comment: https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/v3.3.9/proc/readproc.c

Comment: the source code at procps-v3.3.9/proc/readproc.c:114,  please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With g++ 5.4.0, I was able to compile `readproc.c` (https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/v3.3.9/proc/readproc.c) by:

- Replacing `restrict` with `__restrict`__ (all 39 occurrences).
  While `restrict` is a valid keyword in C (introduced with C99), the C++ standard does not define it. GCC and clang do support the `__restrict__`keyword as an extension.

  For more details on `restrict`, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict.
- Adding `-fpermissive` to the compilation command line. This relaxes some compiler errors (such as for invalid pointer casts) and turns them into warnings. Make sure to review the generated warnings, so that actual errors are not overlooked.

Since the code pasted above was taken from that file, I assume it should compile, too (although I haven't seen myself the error you reported).

Comment: I have got some new keyword,  such as restrict, -fpermissive , attribute ..